# Offending lines appears while running ansible playbook to git clone a project

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

Hi I am trying to clone a project with ansible but I keep getting the below error

```
ERROR! this task 'git' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, shell, script, include, include_vars, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta

The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/ansible/roles/rolename/tasks/main.yml': line 67, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - git: repo=ssh://git@git.example.sample.net:/component/exact/repo.git
    ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/ansible/roles/rolename/tasks/main.yml': line 67, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - git: repo=ssh://git@git.example.sample.net:/component/exact/repo.git
    ^ here

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Ansible task I have is

```
  - git: repo=ssh://git@git.example.sample.net:/component/exact/repo.git
         dest=/home/
         accept_hostkey = true
         version= {{someversion}}
         accept_hostkey = true
```

I have other tasks in my playbook as well but those works fine but whenever I am including git it fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equal sign syntax is only used when you're using the one-line format for modules; when you split them onto multiple lines, you should pass a YAML hash using the `key: value` syntax:

```
- git:
    repo: ssh://git@git.example.sample.net:/component/exact/repo.git
    dest: /home/
    accept_hostkey: true
    version: "{{someversion}}"
```

Comment: @smiller171 Were you disagreeing with me, or with a now-deleted comment?

Comment: nah, the other comment was deleted. Can't edit comments, so I'm gonna go ahead and delete it.